# TemplateDoesNotExist at / django

Tags: django, python-3.x

Got an error

[image]

views.py:

```
def index(request):
        user = request.user
        return render(request, 'main_app/index.html',{'user': user})
```

Tried this:

```
'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
```

But didn't help

cmd:

```
Internal Server Error: /
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 35, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 128, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/main_app/views.py", line 10, in index
    return render(request, 'main_app/index.html',{'user': user})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/shortcuts.py", line 36, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 61, in render_to_string
    template = get_template(template_name, using=using)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 19, in get_template
    raise TemplateDoesNotExist(template_name, chain=chain)
django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: main_app/index.html
```

File structure:
[image]

Django 2.0

Settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
# 'main_app.apps.MainAppConfig',
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'main_app'
```

]

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
```

]

Comment: hi, I dont think you need to write 'main_app/index.html'. just 'index.html'. I think

Comment: @AHBensiali sadly didn't help to solve the issue

Comment: how is your urls.py ?

Comment: youre using BASE_PATH. you need PROJECT_ROOT. BASE_DIR        = os.path.basename( PROJECT_APP_PATH )
PROJECT_ROOT    = BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(PROJECT_APP_PATH)

Comment: Your django is looking at /templates/main_app/index.html. thats why

Comment: @AHBensiali seems right, can you write precisely what I need to write in my setting.py file to make it work? I managed to make it work like this:         `'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'django_direct/main_app/templates')],`

Answer (score 0):

BASE_DIR is the root dir
You need an PROJECT_APP_PATH to the individual apps called:

```
PROJECT_APP_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(PROJECT_APP_PATH, 'templates')
        ],
```

Answer (score 0):

You should move your template from `main_app/templates` to a nested subfolder `main_app/templates/main_app`.

This is explained, for example, in the [django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial03/#write-views-that-actually-do-something)

Comment: nope..... The issue with this is it stops consistency. each project should have a templates folder. It allows you to keep each module self-contained.

Comment: Hm... the docs (see the link in my answer) suggest using a subfolder inside the `templates` directory in each app. This helps to keep the apps from interfering between each other; the docs call it `Template namespacing`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to include your app in the installed apps and it's name spelled corectly

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
# 'main_app.apps.MainAppConfig',
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'main_app.apps.Main_appConfig'
]
```